# Output dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a nested dictionary in the following format, used for internationalization (this allows our translators and non-programmers to edit this file as necessary; my backup plan is to use JSON format, but this would not be as suitable for these users..).

```
dict[LANGUAGE][KEY] = VALUE
```

I output this into a csv file in the following format:

```
KEY, VALUE-LANG-1, ... VALUE-LANG-N
```

where VALUE-LANG-I = dict[LANGUAGE-I][KEY]

This works fine, so long as the VALUEs are simple strings.  I run into a problem, though, if the VALUE is anything more complex (a nested dict or a list).  Is there a way to handle this robustly?

Comment: How exactly would you like it to be handled if the value is not a string?

Comment: CSV is a very dumb, flat data format. It's not remotely up to the task of abritarily nested collections. So if you don't have a fixed-depth format...

Comment: I think you're doing the i18n stuff the wrong way. Check out gettext.

Comment: JSON really isn't that bad and lends itself to easy conversion back into Python objects.  Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to suggest an alternative format suitable for manual editing by non-technical users without knowing the exact details of the data structures you want to store there (e.g. the nested dicts/lists that you mention).

One obvious suggestion is to stick with a computer-friendly format and provide a usable GUI for editing those files.